# Export Flash workspace to image

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I want to make a game in Adobe Flash, something looks like drawing game. (example Ms.Paint)
I'm using Actionscript2. is there a method for me to make save button at that game which that button will export the current image/draw that user make into computer, and it's format will be PNG or JPG. 
I'm sorry my english is too bad but i hope you'll understand me

Answer (score 0):

From Actionscript2 you cant save the image directly. you need to use php or other server scripts to save the image. Check my post related to this [link](http://subashflash.blogspot.com/2013/10/save-image-from-as2-project-using-as3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you desire using only AS2. Perhaps start with using the 'SharedObject' This will allow you/the user to save from flash.

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedData")
```

There is more info on how a sharedObject will work here in AS2

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001508.html